# Laravel Validator facade fails with file input

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a modal form that submits a file to the controller. I validate using the Validate facade. EVerytime i upload file it says no file(My validation fail response). This code was working perfectly i can't figure out what causes this issue

```
<form enctype ="multipart/form-data" action = "/profile_image" method = "POST">
<label>Your Profile Image</label>
<input type = "file" name = "avatar">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type = "submit" class= "pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">Upload image</input>
</form>
```

Here is my controller

```php
public function userImage(Request $request){

    $post = $request->all();
    $val = \Validator::make($request->all(),
        ['avatar' => 'required']);

    if ($val->fails()) {                    
        echo "no file";           
    } else{
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time().'.'.$avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->save('resources/assets/avatars',$filename);
            $user=\Auth::user();
            $user->avatar=$filename;
            $user->save();
        } else {
            echo "No file found";
        }
    }
}
```

I get this response

```
if ($val->fails()) {                    
  echo "no file";           
}
```

I dont understand what makes validator to fail

Comment: If you `dd($request->all())` what is the output you get

Comment: Check the output of `$val->errors()` to see what the failure was.

Comment: well... you ougth to invoke `Request::hasFile($fieldname)` or `Input::hasFile($fieldname)` instead. It should work for you.